# undefined reference to WinMain@16 C++

Tags: c++, codeblocks, winmain

I'm learning in C++, and I've been watching tutorials on thenewboston.org. I'm trying to place classes in different files. When compiling in Codeblocks, I get the message, "undefined reference to WinMain@16". This is my code:

Burrito.cpp

```
  #include "Burrito.h"
  #include <iostream>

   using namespace std;

    Burrito::Burrito()
   {
    cout << "Im a burrito!"<< endl;
    }
```

Burrito.h

```
        #ifndef BURRITO_H
        #define BURRITO_H


        class Burrito
        {
        public:
        Burrito();

         };

         #endif // BURRITO_H
```

main.cpp

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include "Burrito.h"
     using namespace std;

     int main()
     {
         Burrito Obj1;
         return 0;
      }
```

- All files are saved in the same directory
- I'm using windows 8 x64
- codeblocks latestversion